# Display PDF as Image in HTML

Tags: python, html, pdf

What is the best way to display a pdf in your browser using HTML?

The main goal here is to display the pdf as if it was a normal image. The user of the website uploads a pdf file, this file gets separated in his different pages using PyPDF and then each page should be displayed on the webpage. So with each page as a different image.

This would be ideal:

```
<img src="test_page1.pdf">
<img src="test_page2.pdf">
```

I have been trying to do this by using ImageMagick (Python) to convert my pdf's to images however this causes some difficulties:

- Crashes sometimes
- The quality of the image severely decreases
- Size increases

Is there a better way to accomplisch this? I would prefer a non-server dependent method if that exists!

Answer (score 3):

Not client-side, but...

```
exec("convert sample.pdf sample.jpeg")
```

Using `ImageMagick`, http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php / http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python

I think you would really struggle to do this client side. Server side is likely more powerful and can create better quality images faster and with more customisation.

Answer (score 2):

convert is ok but I got best results with [evince-thumbnailer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince). This performs about 8x faster for equal quality (YMMV).

On the down side, while evince-thumbnailer does not have the ghostscript dependency, it *does* introduce several other gnome related dependencies such as glib and gtk.

You can also use one of the [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) tools like pdftops. These are much faster than convert as well and have almost no dependencies, but quality won't be the same.

Here's some command lines for posterity..
I've run a fullpage 300dpi test and added the results.
Note I'm using very big output files for mouse-over magnifying the thumbnail. You can just as well use smaller jpg's for faster results.

```
# This produces perfect png at 2480 pixels width.
# Takes averagely long (45sec).
# 2480 is A4 pixel width at 300dpi
evince-thumbnailer -s 2480 -l input.pdf /tmp/output.png
convert /tmp/output.png -quality 85% output.jpg

# This renders perfect jpg at 2400 pixels width.
# Takes extremely long. (6m)
# Quality is comparable
convert -density 300x300 input.pdf -resize 2400x -units PixelsPerInch \
    -quality 85% output.jpg

# This uses poppler to convert to ps and then converts to jpg.
# Takes averagely long (45sec)
# Does not compete quality-wise.
pdftops -l 1 -r 2400 -paper A4 input.pdf /tmp/output.ps
convert /tmp/output.ps output.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out http://view.samurajdata.se/. You can use this tool to display PDF as image in HTML. Its open source and simple to use.

Please note this method uses PHP.

Comment: Me too was looking for same few days back. Looks I found it. Now let me try to port it to C#.

Answer (score -2):

PDF stands for Portable Document Format. Today it can be used to display documents online by embed a pdf html coding. Let us see the different methods on how to insert a pdf in HTML

Normally inserting a PDF file in HTML is super easy. Here are few methods:-

```html
<embed src="your_pdf_name.pdf" width="1000px" height="2400px" />
```

Inserting a pdf from your PC file

```html
<embed src=”yourfilepath/your_pdf_name.pdf” type=”application/pdf” width=”100%” height=”500px” />
```

You can adjust your width and height as much as you like.
or else the other way to add a pdf is using the `<iframe>` tag

```html
<iframe src="URL" height="400" width="600"></iframe>
```

or else

```html
<iframe src="your_pdf_name.pdf" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;border: none;"></iframe>
```

or else if it’s from a link and or google drive (any cloud storage service)

```html
<iframe src="https//your link from the drive" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```